# Find all lat/lon points within a lat/lon/radius

Tags: php

I have an array of zipcodes with lat/lon coordinates that look like:

```
array:4 [
  "04543" => array:3 [
    "latitude" => "44.0300"
    "longitude" => "-69.5100"
    "hits" => 0
  ]
  "04547" => array:3 [
    "latitude" => "43.9800"
    "longitude" => "-69.3300"
    "hits" => 0
  ]
  90210 => array:3 [
    "latitude" => "34.0900"
    "longitude" => "-118.4100"
    "hits" => 0
  ]
  "06042" => array:3 [
    "latitude" => "41.7900"
    "longitude" => "-72.5300"
    "hits" => 0
  ]
]
```

I would like to loop through this array one zip at a time and for that zip determine if there are other zips that are within 140 miles from the lat/lon for that zip. If there are other points, then I would like to add them to the 'hits" key. The idea is that if zipcode A is too close to zipcode B and Zipcode C then ZipCode A will have a hit value of 2 since it is close to 2 zipcodes. And vice versa since Zipcode B was close to Zipcode A, it should have a hit value of 1 assuming it is not close to Zip code C.

This is what I have tried so far but I feel it may not be correct as I may be over simplifying.

Any tips? It seems to work OK with some of my test data.

```
$maskedInputZips = $validInputZips;

    foreach ($validInputZips as $zip => $latlon) {

        foreach ($maskedInputZips as $maskedZip => $maskedLatlon) {

            if ($zip != $maskedZip) {
                $miles = $this->haversineGreatCircleDistance($latlon['latitude'], $latlon['longitude'], $maskedLatlon['latitude'], $maskedLatlon['longitude'], 3959);

                if ($miles < (140)) {

                    $validInputZips[$zip]['hits'] += 1;

                }
            }
        }
    }


protected function haversineGreatCircleDistance($latitudeFrom, $longitudeFrom, $latitudeTo, $longitudeTo, $earthRadius = 3959)
    {
        // convert from degrees to radians
        $latFrom = deg2rad($latitudeFrom);
        $lonFrom = deg2rad($longitudeFrom);
        $latTo = deg2rad($latitudeTo);
        $lonTo = deg2rad($longitudeTo);

        $latDelta = $latTo - $latFrom;
        $lonDelta = $lonTo - $lonFrom;

        $angle = 2 * asin(sqrt(pow(sin($latDelta / 2), 2) +
                cos($latFrom) * cos($latTo) * pow(sin($lonDelta / 2), 2)));
        return $angle * $earthRadius;
    }
```

Comment: Is there an actual error or are you just looking for a kind of ["code review"](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Kind of code review to see if I am missing anything blatantly obvious in my logic. Sorry was not sure if stack overflow allowed this or not.

Comment: Ahhhh just saw your link. I can post my question there. Many thanks for your help

Comment: No problem! You'll more likely get a better response on CodeReview .. it might get closed as "off topic" here on SE

Comment: Yes I'll close this one and just use that one. Thannks man. I didnt know that site existed :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on code review